# App not available for Samsung galaxy Y on google play

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I've published an app in Google Play Store. The App is not available in Samsung galaxy Y. I even added the following permission, but didn't work

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />


 <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
                android:smallScreens="true"
                android:normalScreens="true"
                android:largeScreens="true"
                android:xlargeScreens="true"
                android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Do I need to set any permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: What is your mean "is not available"? It cannot be found or it cannot be installed or run? If it is the first one, I think it is not about AndroidManiftest.xml, it is about google play console.

Comment: what is the minimum sdk version of your app...and also when did you upload your app??

Comment: @Jlazar89 minSdk=8 , target=18

Comment: and when did you upload the app to the play store??

Comment: @buptcoder Actually I've uploaded the update of existing app in alpha testing. But it displays only old app in Samsung galaxy Y.

Comment: @Jlazar89 2 days before

Comment: trying searching your app in the playstore with its package name .

Comment: @Jlazar89  I've uploaded the update of existing app in alpha testing. But it displays only old app in Samsung galaxy Y. Its available for other recent devices